# Kivy: Update CheckBox State without call 'on_active' method

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have this simple code here: a  `CheckBox`  and a  `Widget`  where I want to add the CheckBox.
When the App starts I want to update the  `CheckBox.state` from a dictionary or from a .json file. Here I directly typed `'down'`.
The main problem is that when I update the state from `'normal'` to `'down'` it calls the method `on_action:`  and here I have some function that I want to call just when I press the CheckBox.
How can I initialize `CheckBox.state` (from a dict or .json file -> I know how to do that) without call that `on_action` that executes my function there.

```
class AddCheckBox(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddCheckBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        check_box = ChBox()
        check_box.update_state = 'down'
        self.add_widget(check_box)

class ChBox(CheckBox):
    update_state = StringProperty('normal')
    def some_function(self):
        print("Function is called")
```

```
AddCheckBox:
<AddCheckBox>:
<ChBox>:
    state: root.update_state
    on_active: root.some_function()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this, in a sort of clunky approach, by defining a `Property` `ignore_state_change`, like this:

```
class ChBox(CheckBox):
    update_state = StringProperty('normal')
    ignore_state_change = BooleanProperty(True)

    def some_function(self):
        if self.ignore_state_change:
            return
        print("Function is called")

    def on_parent(self, *args):
        self.ignore_state_change = False
```

The `on_parent()` method changes the `ignore_state_change` to not ignore any state changes after that.